# How to get the intent using the CLU instead of using LUIS

Tags: python, azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I want to get the intent according to the user input in a chatbot and I want to get it using the CLU instead of using LUIS.

in the code below is how i do it using LUIS:

```
var result = await LuisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
var topIntent = result?.GetTopScoringIntent();
var intent = (topIntent != null) ? topIntent.Value.intent : null;
var value = turnContext.Activity.Value;
```

i want to do the same but using the CLU.
Note: the CLU is already configured.

Answer (score 0):

To get intent using CLU you check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/conversational-language-understanding/tutorials/bot-framework#identify-integration-points) documentation.

As per documentation once you have `cluResult` with `cluRecoginzer`, you can get the intent with `cluResult.TopIntent().intent`.

For complete example please check this [repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-service-language-samples/tree/main/CoreBotWithCLU) and for more details please check [DotNet CLU Recognizer](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/ConversationLanguageUnderstanding/dotnet).